# Query via rest gives 403 unauthorized when in reverse proxy

Tags: jira

With my user I'm free to make any query I want, anyway if I try via REST I get 403. 
Do I need to give some additional permission to my user?

**Edit:**
It seems it only happens when I go to port 80, in my reverse proxy configuration (I followed the guide [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/proxying-atlassian-server-applications-with-apache-http-server-mod_proxy_http-806032611.html) ). I tried with 8080, direct access, and it works.

Comment: What specific REST API are you using that threw a 403?

Comment: Search api, I just want to make a jql query. And my user has an admin profile and from the browser I can see every project so it has to be something related with the REST

Comment: Edited: it seems to be related to the reverse proxy conf